# WPF animation on a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, listbox

Do you know any example of how to animate the insertion of an item on a `ListBox`? 
The effect I was thinking of is something like:

- At first we have items `A` and `B` on the `ListBox`.
- Than a `C` item is inserted between `A`
  and `B`.
- In the effect I imagined, before `C` is inserted, `A` and `B`
  become gradually more distant until a
  `C` element fits in between. When we reach this point, `C` is finnally inserted.

My problem is that, even though I already did something about templates (that I could animate), I don't know how to slowly separate two items on the `ListBox`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert the C item first, but with height 0 and with its content hidden (or transparent).  Then animate the height of the C item to its full height: this will push A and B apart.  Finally, make the content of the C item visible (or animate its opacity into visbility).